# Rails: command line not finish when create second model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am tring to create a new rails app and generate some models
First, when I try to use the `rails g model category name:string` command, it finishes normally.

But, when I generate another model using `rails g model product name:string`, the command does not finish. I have to press `ctrl + c` to finish it. It just happened today, how do I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['rails generate' commands hang when trying to create a model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857365/rails-generate-commands-hang-when-trying-to-create-a-model)

Comment: Seems like a problem due to `spring`